# Custom Theme in WordPress Doesn't display anything

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have started learning WordPress.
My custom theme doesn't display anything. The following is the code.

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: My First Theme
Theme URI: http://localhost/wordpress/
Author: Itsmee
Author URI: https://abcd.com
Description: Basic WordPress theme for Sitepoint theme building tutorial
Text Domain: bsimple
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
*/
```

index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @package My_First_Theme
 */

get_header();
?>

//content HTML here

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

header.php

```
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    
      <title>Bootstrap Template - Index</title>
      <meta content="" name="description">
      <meta content="" name="keywords">
    
      <!-- Favicons -->
      <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
      <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
    
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700|Raleway:300,400,400i,500,500i,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    
      <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
      <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/vendor/nivo-slider/css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
      <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      
    </head>
```

Footer.php

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
//Footer scripts and other contents
```

Successfully created the theme and activated it in the backend But couldn't see anything in the front end seems like the theme files are not rendered.

Please help! Thx.

Comment: Assuming this is on localhost, have you enabled debug logging in the `wp_config.php`?

Comment: Hi @Daniel. Yes this is in Local. I will check and feedback

Comment: Yes enabled. But no difference.

Comment: Two things: 1) `<?php wp_head(); ?>` needs to be placed somewhere between `<head>` and `</head>` (usually right before `</head>`), not outside as you have it now; and 2) that's not the proper way to add stylesheets & JS files to the head section. Please see: [Theme Handbook - Including CSS & JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/).

Comment: please refer this : https://websitesetup.org/wordpress-theme-development/  for theme development in wordpress. this may help you